# Undo ripple delete in davinci resolve

Tags: davinci-resolve

Is there a way to undo a ripple delete much later?

Long time after I lost the ability to ctrl-z my way back, I regret cutting out a section of the clip and I want it back. Anyway to find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  If you’re running out of undos, you can increase the max number of undos, or you can version more frequently.  Versioning in most apps is simply, “Save As,” but Resolve works differently.

An easy way to version at the project level In Resolve is to turn on auto-save.  At any point, if you want to revert to an old version, you can restore a project backup from the contextual menu in the project manager.

Personally, I like to version at the timeline level, though.  So, periodically, I’ll duplicate my current timeline, and increment its name with a version number.  Then, if I want to open an old version, I can just open an old timeline.  The advantage is that in Resolve, you can have two timelines open at the same time, but not two projects.*  So, copy/pasting or drag/drop from an old version to a new one is easy.

*Technically, turning on “dynamic project switching” lets you have two projects “open” in memory at the same time, but they can’t both be visible in the UI, simultaneously.